# Double click .exe file to generate .DAT file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a requirement to open the `.exe` files, which will create `.DAT` file (contains data) in the same path. When I tried using execute process task and script task to open the .exe file. I can only see the `.exe` executing but not opening. As a result,`.DAT` file is not generated. Can you help me how to resolve this? Because executing the .exe file is not what is required. Double-clicking on the file only generates the file.

Comment: From SSIS you can call the exe and pass the arguments if that exe accept. Explore the exe and check what arguments will do double clicking work and implement in SSIS. Alternatively if you are able to do this from CMD put it in batch file and call batch file from execute process task.

Comment: What do you think the difference is between double-clicking an .exe and executing it?

Comment: From where you are executing the package: SQl agent job, visual studio, dtexec??